# How to embed an image inside a Google Document comment?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I add comments all the time to Google Documents, however i would like to embed images inside Google Document comments (similar to how you can add images to facebook comments). Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot embed images inside your Google Drive document comments box, you may only put a link to an image if exists online somewhere.

Comment: right.. @VasilisKosmas when i work with platforms that limit my choice like that.. i usually those random free image hosting sites.. but obviously i can't do this with documents that have confidential information. Is there a way to upload such images to google drive itself.. and link to it immediately (ie witthout going through download/permission screens etc)?

Comment: yeah can be done by 1. uploading the image to google drive 2. clicking on the share doc and getting the shareable link 3. posting that link on comment

Comment: @VasilisKosmas if you answer the question i'll give you the correct answer award

Comment: yes, you can upload an image in your Google Drive then right-click on it (Google Drive interface) > Share > Set up your access settings and then click on Copy URL. Use this URL to paste it into your Google Drive Document comment

Comment: I cannot post an answer, I stay with my comments since they are not directly solve your initial issue on your published question. As concerning your comment about giving me award, it is not something that is bargained through this board. Also I see that you had already answered correctly to your sub-question, so we are ok :)

Answer (score 1):

from [Vasilis Kosmas](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/116706/vasilis-kosmas) [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90183/how-to-embed-an-image-inside-a-google-document-comment#comment78841_90183):

> you can upload an image in your Google Drive then right-click on it (Google Drive interface) > Share > Set up your access settings and then click on Copy URL. Use this URL to paste it into your Google Drive Document comment